# python passing a variable to an object property or method through a function argument

Tags: python, django

I've been trying to construct a generic function (a Django view handler) whose arguments are  contains  specific object property to use inside the function

something like (simplified):

```
def some_function(arg, property):
    return Some_Object.property
```

but python tries to treat 'property' as the property/method name instead of treating it like a variable.

I tried multiple variants but none worked. (didn't try exec/eval varient  - should I? doesn't seem too pythonic)

I know that I can pass a function or an object as an argument. but didn't seem to find the exact solution here
using python 2.7 and 2.6

the specific implantation is a Django issue but I got curious about this

Comment: `eval` considered harmful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you want to do is use getattr to retrive the property:

```
def some_function(arg, property):
    return getattr(Some_Object, propery)
```

You can see the documentation here: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr

Comment: arghhh getattr - python silver bullet. I've should have thought about it myself. thanks alot @Trevor!